# how can i get age from date of birth in neo4j

Tags: date, neo4j, cypher

I´m starting with neo4j and would like to know how to get the age in years.
I have the node  below

```
(p1:Person{id:1,birthdate:"1989-10-03",name:"Person1"})
```

tried something like this

```
with p.birthdate as bd, date() as d return d - bd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`date`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/) and [`duration`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-durations) types, for instance like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Person1"})
WITH duration.between(date(p.birthdate), date()) as d
RETURN d, d.years, d.months, d.days
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like APOC functions (Awesome Procedures on Cypher) then below script will work:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Person1"})
RETURN ( apoc.date.convert(timestamp(), 'ms', 'd') - 
         apoc.date.parse(p.birthdate, 'd', 'YYY-MM-DD')) / 365 as yearsAlive
```

Result:

```
╒════════════╕
│"yearsAlive"│
╞════════════╡
│33          │
└────────────┘
```

Ref:

- 1.https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/#:~:text=APOC%20is%20an%20add%2Don,all%20APOC%20functions%20and%20procedures
- 2.https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/overview/apoc.date/